# How do you properly set up ssl on and installation of postfix using zpanel

Tags: ssl, postfix-mta, dovecot

So about a week ago I worked on setting up a mail server for my company's mail service. I ended up using zpanel to make it easier to create new mail accounts. Zpanel uses postfix and dovecot that is configured via the installation. I've been trying to set up ssl on this server using a self signed certificate but I continue to receive a your server doesn't support ssl.

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# postfix config file

# uncomment for debugging if needed
soft_bounce=yes

# postfix main
mail_owner = postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
delay_warning_time = 4

# postfix paths
html_directory = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES

# network settings
inet_interfaces = all
mydomain = mail.thetactilegroup.com
myhostname = mail.thetactilegroup.com
mynetworks = all
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf

# mail delivery
recipient_delimiter = +

# mappings
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
#local_recipient_maps =

# virtual setup
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-    virtual_alias_maps.cf,
                 regexp:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/zpanel/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-            virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-    virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 150
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

# debugging
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

# authentication
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

# tls config
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_use_tls = yes
#smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
#smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
#tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtp_tls_session_cache
# Change mail.example.com.* to your host name
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.in.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.in.pem
# smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/root.crt

# rules restrictions
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
# uncomment for realtime black list checks
#       ,reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
#       ,reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
#       ,reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net

smtpd_helo_required = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
message_size_limit = 52428800
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the Postfix master(5) manual page.
#
# ***** Unused items removed *****
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
submission inet   n       -       -       -       -      smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o     smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
#  -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
  -o content_filter= 
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
# ====================================================================
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
# spam/virus section
#
smtp-amavis  unix  -    -       y       -       2       smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
  -o smtpd_bind_address=127.0.0.1
  -o smtpd_helo_required=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o disable_vrfy_command=no
  -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
#
# Dovecot LDA
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
#
# Vacation mail
vacation    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Rq user=vacation argv=/var/spool/vacation/vacation.pl -f ${sender} --             ${recipient}
```

How would I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
    mydomain = mail.thetactilegroup.com
    myhostname = mail.thetactilegroup.com
```

convert to this

```
mydomain = thetactilegroup.com
myhostname = mail.thetactilegroup.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to enable smtp_use_tls:

```
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Additionally, I recommend the following switches:

```
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, aDSS, aECDSA
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
```

You can read more about here http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this in master.cf:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Save and restart Postfix:
    service postfix restart